# How to resolve XSS vulnerabilities while using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have to use some HTML tags in innerHTML. But it's giving some security issues. I can't use innerText etc because I have to show HTML content instead of plain text.

$(this).parent()[0].innerHTML = newInnerHTML;

What are the workarounds for this. or is there a way to resolve the vulnerabilities. I tried sanitizing the HTML but it didn't work. Please provide your suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use `innerHTML`. There are much better alternatives, e.g. [`<template>`: The Content Template element](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template), [`createElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement), [`cloneNode`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), [`replaceChildren`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren), etc.

Comment: There's no workaround, the only way (additionally to `<template>` Sebastian brought up above) is to pass real data (i.e. content without tags) and create the elements dynamically, and put the content using `textContent` or `innerText`. See also https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you tried sanitizing it already, but maybe you were doing it wrong. If you need to put user input as an `innerHTML` string without a risk of xss, you can use a library like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xss-clean to sanitize only the user input. If the html content is hard coded, there isn't a risk of xss. The risk of using `innerHTML` only applies when a user can submit an HTML string to a server that could be visible to other users.

Comment: I modified it to $(this).parent()[0]["innerHTML"] = newInnerHTML and now I don't see any issues after scanning app for vulnerabilities.